# Two definitions of real flag manifolds: do they coincide?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Let $G$ be a real semisimple Lie group with finite center.

**Definition 1**
A *real flag manifold* is a homogeneous space $G/Q$ where 
$Q$ is a parabolic subgroup of $G$.

**Definition 2**
Let $K$ be a maximal compact subgroup of $G$ and $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak k+\mathfrak p$ the Cartan decomposition. A *real flag manifold* is an
adjoint orbit of $K$ in $\mathfrak p$.

> **Question**  Do these definitions coincide?

Since $K$ acts transitively on $G/Q$, we have $K/K\cap Q=G/Q$. Therefore I guess
the problem amounts to showing that $K\cap Q$ is the centralizer in $K$ of a certain element $h_0$ in the Cartan subspace $\mathfrak a \subset\mathfrak p$ which defines $Q$. I can easily see that $\mathfrak k\cap \mathfrak q$ is the centralizer of $h_0$ in $\mathfrak k$, so this already shows that 
$K/K\cap Q$ and $K/Z_K(h_0)$ coincide up to covering.